# using nodejs instead of comet for longpolling

Tags: mysql, node.js

The idea is to use nodejs instead of comet for longpolling.
The intention is to spot changes in database and flush the update to several users.
Any ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comet is a grouping term for ajax technologies. It's a way of doing long polling.

node.js is evented IO. Specifically you would use it to run a HTTP server.

node.js does not mix well with your current serverside (probably php). Yes you can use node.js with socket.io to do communication between client and server.

I would personally advice againts using mysql as your database for node though. It's more suited to document based noSQL databases.

Comment: thank you very much for the advice.
What according to you would be better for this situation

Comment: @user597441 What is your website. What do you have so far. If your you want to use node.js either create a websocket server with node or create your entire website in node. Do you want to port your entire website to node?

Comment: Not exactly a website, but this is the scenario
There are about 100 users and each one of them have to be simultaneous be informed about the database changes.
Polling doesn't seem to be working properly so I thought nodejs would be a better solution.

Comment: @user597441 yes you can use socket.io with nodejs. You still need to understand that nodejs is a server, polling is a communication method.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the comment about MySQL being less suitable with node? I don't see anything in the design of node that supports that. The only thing I would agree with is that it works very well with MongoDB, being Javascript/JSON on both.

Comment: @justinhj All I said was that it's more suited to document based noSQL databases. Also mysql is a very silly database, if your going to SQL at least postgresql

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on comet but for your specific scenario I would advise you to go with socket.io for pushing the updates from the server.

Take a look at this example > https://github.com/andrewdavey/vogue

See how he is using socket.io to push the stuff to the client. MySql is not recommended but it's fairly workable.

Comment: Hi nEEBz. Is it possible to create channels , subscribe to/unsubscribe from channels using socket.io.

Comment: I havent used sockets myself but I think you can. For each use case you could setup channels, not sure if that's a really good strategy as it'll put quite a load on network.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js and Comet are not the same thing. A server written in JavaScript running in Node can use Comet or WebSockets (both nicely abstracted in the module socket.io).